# Using Powershell to convert a file's contents into a string that can be transferred using JSON

Tags: json, powershell

How does one convert a text file's contents into a string and then insert this string into a JSON file?

For example, if a file contains:

```
this
is
a
sample
file
```

The script would generate:

```
"this\r\nis\r\na\r\nsample\r\nfile"
```

To insert into a JSON template:

```
"something":"<insertPoint>"
```

To produce:

```
"something":"this\r\nis\r\na\r\nsample\r\nfile"
```

I'm using Powershell 5 and have managed to load the file, generate some JSON and insert it by running:

```
# get contents and convert to JSON
$contentToInsert = Get-Content $sourceFilePath -raw | ConvertTo-Json
# write in output file
(Get-Content $outputFile -Raw).replace('<insertPoint>', $contentToInsert) | Set-Content $outputFile
```

However, a lot of other, unwanted fields are also added.

```
"something":"{
  "value":  "this\r\nis\r\na\r\nsample\r\nfile"
  "PSPath":  "C:\\src\\intro.md",
  "PSParentPath":  "C:\\src",
  "PSChildName":  "intro.md",
    etc...
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to send small rich text segments to a web page via JSON but want to edit and store them locally using Markdown. If this doesn't make sense and there's a better way of sending these then please let me know also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571362/45375) helpfully suggests not using *string* manipulation to create JSON in PowerShell, but to use hashtables (or custom objects) to construct the data and *then* convert it to JSON.

However, that alone does *not* solve your problem:

```sh
PS> @{ something = Get-Content -Raw $sourceFilePath } | ConvertTo-Json
{
  "something": {
    "value": "this\nis\na\nsample\nfile\n",
    "PSPath": "/Users/mklement/Desktop/pg/lines.txt",
    # ... !! unwanted properties are still there
}
```

The **root cause of the problem is that `Get-Content` decorates the strings it outputs with metadata** in the form of `NoteProperty` properties, and  `ConvertTo-Json` currently *invariably* includes these.

- A proposal to allow opting out of this decoration when calling `Get-Content` can be found in [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537).
- Complementarily, [GitHub issue #5797](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5797) suggests that `ConvertTo-Json` should ignore the extra properties for primitive .NET types such as *strings*.

The simplest **workaround** is to **access the underlying .NET instance with `.psobject.baseobject`**, which bypasses the invisible wrapper object PowerShell uses to supply the extra properties:

```sh
PS> @{ something = (Get-Content -Raw $sourceFilePath).psobject.baseobject } |
      ConvertTo-Json
{
  "something": "this\nis\na\nsample\nfile\n"
}
```

Comment: "the simplest workaround is to access the underlying .NET instance with .psobject.baseobject" < yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just a *general recommendation* apart from the actually issue described by @mklement0 and metadata added to the `Get-Content` results:

**Do *not* poke** (replace, insert, etc.) in any `Json` content.
Instead, **modify the *object*** (if necessary, use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) to restore the object) prior converting it into ([`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6)) a `Json` file.
In this example, I would use a [`hash-table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) with a [`here-string`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/31/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) for this:

```
@{'something' = @'
this
is
a
sample
file
'@
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Result:

```
{
    "something":  "this\nis\na\nsample\nfile"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Out-String` cmdlet to coerce the output of `Get-Content` into a flat string first:

```
@{ "something" = (Get-Content lines.txt | Out-String) } | ConvertTo-Json
```

This produces:

```
{
    "something":  "this\r\nis\r\na\r\nsample\r\nfile\r\n"
}
```

Comment: Your solution is effective, but deserves an explanation: The OP's use of `Get-Content -Raw` already guarantees use of a single, multi-line string, and `-Raw` is generally the simpler and faster approach (`Out-String`'s purpose is to get _formatted-for-display_ string representation of arbitrary command output).
That said, use of `Out-String` does fix the OP's problem in this case, because, by creating a _new_ string from the ones output by `Get-Content` _without the `NoteProperty` members that the latter adds_, `ConvertTo-Json` produces the intended serialization.

Comment: P.S.: It likely won't matter in this case, but it's worth noting in general that the `Get-Content` / `Out-String` combination won't faithfully preserve the last input line's trailing-newline-or-not status, and will always append a final newline; `Get-Content -Raw`, by contrast, does not have this problem.